# IronPython with DynamicObject subclass

Tags: c#, ironpython, dynamicobject

I have a class inheriting from `DynamicObject` which I need to expose through `IronPython`.
I can access dynamic properties with no problems, but plain old properties don't work.

This is a slightly simplified implementation of my object:

```
class Foo : DynamicObject 
{
    Dictionary<string, object> _dynamicMembers = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    public Foo()
    {
        _dynamicMembers.Add("dynamicProperty", 0);
    }

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        return _dynamicMembers.TryGetValue(binder.Name, out result);
    }

    public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, object value)
    {
        if (_dynamicMembers.ContainsKey(binder.Name))
        {
            _dynamicMembers[binder.Name] = value;
            return true;
        }

        return base.TrySetMember(binder, value);
    }

    public string PlainOldProperty { get; set; }
}
```

And this is a `NUnit` test case which demostrates the problem:

```
[TestFixture]
public class FooTest
{
    [Test]
    public void CanSetDynamicProperty()
    {
        var engine = IronPython.Hosting.Python.CreateEngine();
        var scope = engine.CreateScope();

        dynamic foo = new Foo();

        scope.SetVariable("foo", foo);

        engine.Execute("foo.dynamicProperty = 1", scope);

        Assert.AreEqual(1, foo.dynamicProperty);
    }

    [Test]
    public void CanSetPlainOldProperty()
    {
        var engine = IronPython.Hosting.Python.CreateEngine();
        var scope = engine.CreateScope();

        dynamic foo = new Foo();

        scope.SetVariable("foo", foo);

        engine.Execute("foo.PlainOldProperty = 1", scope);

        Assert.AreEqual(1, foo.PlainOldProperty);
    }
}
```

The first test passes, but the second one does not, because it throws:

> System.MissingMemberException : 'Foo' object has no attribute
>   'PlainOldProperty'

This is because of what happens in `TrySetMember()`: in case the member we're trying to set is not already contained in the dictionary, it delegates the job to `DynamicObject`'s version of `TrySetMember()`.
Which, as it turns out, returns `false`, hence the exception.

But then, how do you set `PlainOldProperty` from `IronPython`? From `C#` it works just fine, as expected.

I'm either missing something or it can't be done.

Furthermore, I tried overriding all the other methods from `DynamicObject` to see if they were being hit by `IronPython`, but no cigar.

Can anyone shed some light on why this happens?